# How to exclude a category from search folder in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I can create a search folder in Outlook 2010 but cannot exclude some categories from that folder. I tried adding filter criteria for category field but it does not seem to have an effect.

Note: I can make a search and filter out some categories. What I am looking for is a way to create a *search folder* with some categories excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the search folder and select "Customize This Search Folder". Click the "Criteria" button and open the "Advanced" tab. On this tab, click the "Field" drop-down and select "All Mail Fields -> Categories". Set "doesn't contain" as a "Condition" and type the name of the category you want to exclude. Add as many exclusions as you want.